# Google analytics not registering my app as a source of traffic to other sites

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, redirect, google-analytics, http-referer

I am working on an app which is a essentially an aggregator of links to other websites. However, instead of linking directly to websites, the links on my app point to an endpoint on my app -- /redirect/:uuid, which in turn performs a 301 redirect to the respective sites:

1. User visits my app -- https://www.myapp.com
2. User clicks on link https://www.myapp.com/redirect/123
3. That results in a 301 redirect to http(s)://external-site.com/?ref=myapp

The issue I am having is that for some reason Google analytics (running on external-site.com) is not attributing the traffic my app is sending to the external-site to my app. It just marks it as direct traffic.

My app is a Rails app, hosted on Heroku. In order to do the redirect I am doing `redirect_to "http://external-site.com/?ref=myapp", status: :moved_permanently`

I noticed that if just point my browser to https://www.myapp.com/redirect/123 and then get the 301 redirect to http://external-site.com/?ref=myapp  `document.referrer` is blank. Which I found weird. Shouldn't the browser still send the HTTP Referer header in the case of a 301 redirect?

Would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RFC does not specify a behavior for the Referrer header after a 301, however your problem is about protocols, you are being redirect from a secure `HTTPS` connection. The browser will not send any referrer because this could harm the client security exposing informations about the previous request.
A simple solution would be using `utm` parameters https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en

Comment: Well so if it is redirecting to another page that will be accessed via HTTPS then it should send the referer header correct? Also, I am curious to understand what are the security concerns for such behavior. What's an example of an 'attack' that would exploit this (meaning, sending the HTTP referer header)

Comment: Not sure about that, but I don't think they will be sent anyway.
Think about that, SSL is meant to secure a communication between a client and a server, so I need to be sure any data I exchange with the server will not be read by anyone else. Sending the referer to a third party would expose my latest request, many old sites still send session tokens as GET parameters, search queries, or any sensitive data could be leaked